# How to Send HTML Text Response from a Web Request?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a desktop application that runs on Windows CE with an embedded browser control (IE4, I believe). Windows CE has a limited instruction set. It is limited to HttpWebRequest with it's .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

For this device, I am making a query to our web server.

When we send the product information to the web server, we want it to respond with a very basic HTML page with the information.

On the Windows CE device, I have this code running:

```
private const string _URL = "http://192.168.2.202/query.aspx";

public string QueryProduct(string productID)
{
    var preReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_URL);
    preReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    preReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
    preReq.UserAgent = "WindowsCE Client";
    preReq.Method = "HEAD";
    preReq.Timeout = 10000;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)preReq.GetResponse())
    {
        response.Close(); // seems a bit pointless
    }
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.UserAgent = "WindowsCE Client";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var postData = String.Format("id=1&product={1}", productID);
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
    data = null;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

That part is working fine, it seems, but it is there just in case something isn't right.

Now, my ASP.NET file **query.aspx** is a simple single page file (i.e. no code behind):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Product Query</title>
    <script runat="server">
        void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var authID = Request.QueryString["id"];
            var product = Request.QueryString["product"];
            txtAuthenticationID.Text = authID;
            txtProduct.Text = product;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authID) &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
            {
                Search_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
        void Search_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var authID = txtAuthenticationID.Text.Trim();
            var product = txtProduct.Text.Trim();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(authID) &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
            {
                var htm = String.Format(
                    "<html><head><title>TEST</title></head><body><p>Product: {0}</p><p>End of File</p></body></html>", product);
                Response.Write(htm);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div>Authentication ID: <asp:TextBox ID="txtAuthenticationID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div>Product: <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Search_Click" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea up there is to return the formatted HTML text only if the two (2) values *authID* and *product* exist, otherwise show a form that allows someone to specify these values in the provided form.

If I remove the line `Response.End();`, I get my formatted string on top along with the HTML form below.

If I include the line `Response.End();`, I only get the blank form - like nothing was ever entered along the query string.

### What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Uh... hang on. It seems to be working fine this morning. {confused}

Comment: confused here too. First of all, I am wondering how does it respond with your formatted html without you sending the &btnSearch=Search to simulate the button click. It should not raise the button click event!

Comment: You are calling it yourself! : )

Comment: My Windows CE device has a barcode reader. Someone scans the barcode, then my C# code makes the call to the HttpWebRequest - passing it the barcode text as variable `product`. Not the best name choice, but it is still being developed.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - forgot to tag you in the comment above.